# How can we host free selenium containers?

Tags: r, shiny, render, selenium-grid, rselenium

I have three files. These are:

1. app.R
2. Dockerfile
3. compose.yaml

When I run this command two containers open with localhost:3838 and localhost:4445
Docker Command:

```
docker compose up -d
```

**Now can I host my shiny project in render.com?**

**If not, there have any alternative process for hosting shiny app with selenium?**